# Scrolling and selecting a checkbox in a drop down using python webdriver

Tags: python-2.7

I have to select a checkbox from within a drop down. The problem is the value is not visible. I need to scroll down to reach the value.

html

```
<select class="select_box" tabindex="25" id="cbo_CC_CType" 
name="cbo_CC_CType" multiple="multiple" multi-select="true" 
autofillkey="CMDTYPE" title="COMMAND TYPE">
<option value="Authorization">Authorization</option>
<option value="Cancel">Cancel</option>
<option value="Change">Change</option>
<option value="Clear">Clear</option>
<option value="Final">Final</option>
<option value="Final1">Final</option>
<option value="Fina2">Final</option>
<option value="Fina3">Final</option>
.
.
.
.
.
.
<option value="MyCar">MyCar</option>
</select>
```

I tried:

chromedriver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='cbo_CC_CType']/option[@value='MyCar']").click()

Can someone please help